# Routing based on query string parameter name in servicestack?

Tags: servicestack

I want to route two different RequestDTO class according my querystring parameter. PFB the two scenario.

```
Scenario 1:- 

localhost:8080/myservice?type="abc" //Service URL

// should be called below DTO class

public class TypeRequestDTO //DTO
{
   public string type;
}

Scenario 2:- 
--------------------------------------------------
localhost:8080/myservice?Name="xyz" //Service URL

// should be called below DTO class

public class NameRequestDTO //DTO
{
   public string Name;
}
```

In both Scenario, `base url` is same (`/myservice`) but I want to do routing according `querystring parameter`. Is there any possible way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't route by queryString, which is just an attribute used to populate the Request DTO that's handled by the same Service.

But inside the Service you can delegate to a different Services, e.g:

```
[Route("/myservice")]
public class Request
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
}

public class MyService : Service
{
    public object Any(Request request)
    {
        if (request.Type == "abc")
           return Any(request.ConvertTo<AbcRequest>());

       return Any(request.ConvertTo<XyzRequest>());
    }

    public object Any(AbcRequest request) { ... }

    public object Any(XyzRequest request) { ... }
}
```

If the implementation is in a different Service class you can use:

```
return base.ExecuteRequest(request.ConvertTo<AbcRequest>());
```

Which is a short-hand for resolving the Autowired Service from the IOC and executing it, e.g:

```
using (var service = base.ResolveService<AbcService>())
{
    return service.Any(request.ConvertTo<AbcRequest>());
}
```